Kubernetes: what is special about ingress controllers and why are they useful or necessary?
I don't understand why Nginx and HAproxy, among others, have very specific software for Kubernetes called ingress controllers, software that is different from the nginx or haproxy software you would install directly on a UNIX host.
There has to be something I'm missing so I'm going to list a few facts I think are true in hope that somebody can point to my mistake and explain to me why an ingress controller is necessary or useful.
Here are some facts I believe to be true, but that I might be mistaken about (please point to my error if you see it).

for tcp and udp ports below 1024, a load balancer is necessary to direct traffic to the cluster from the internet

on a managed kubernetes cloud, this load balancer is supplied by the hosting company. I can't choose which one to install.

A load balancer is different from an ingress controller, they are totally different things. For example:

an ingress controller doesn't receive traffic directly from the internet while a load balancer does
an ingress controller only deals with http/https traffic, while a load balancer deals with all the ports



So here's my reasoning: if the load balancer does its job, it should be able to direct the internet http/https traffic to some internal ports of my cluster.
So why would I need an Ingress controller?
If I want to dispatch this http/https traffic to different services according to domain names or urls then I could just define a service that runs a docker image of good old Apache or Nginx (not ingress version, just the normal web server you can install on any unix distro and you can find a docker image of on dockerhub). This service, running a normal web server, could be configured as a reverse proxy and redirect http/https traffic to the other services inside the cluster.
What am I missing here? Why what I'm describing wouldn't work and why would an ingress controller be necessary instead?

You understand that it is for routing traffic, you are asking why you would need it if you already have a component directing traffic.
